# How can you pass rails controller data to angular templates assets to create forms?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to make methods and data in a rails controller be accessible in an html.erb asset to be passed to angular?

For example, a form to create groups might look like:

```
<%= form_for :group, url: groups_path do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_area :name, :class => "group_name box_place_holder", :placeholder => "What is your group's name?" %>

    <%= f.text_area :description, :class => "group_description box_place_holder", :placeholder => "Briefly describe your group..." %>

    <%= f.submit 'Create', :class => 'create_group_button' %>

<% end %>
```

Which works fine in the groups view, but using angular-rails-templates (https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates) is there a way to get this form to work in `assets/templates`?

For example for this mdDialog pop-up the template referenced is tabDialog.html.erb, but how can I actually get the data and routes from the groups controller into this asset?

With the angular scope:

```
  $scope.showTabDialog = function(ev) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: DialogController,
      templateUrl: 'tabDialog.html',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose:true
    })
  };
```

and html:

```
<md-button ng-click="showTabDialog($event)">
        Create Group
</md-button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to get some value from your Rails controller into your angular controller?

Comment: That would be one way to do it, like get a user authentication id and just manually write the HTML. But ideally the whole create method and routes would be available so I could just use the rails syntax like above to structure the form. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Haymaker87 in fact, if I could just get `form_authenticity_token` inside the `assets/template/tabDialog.html.erb` it would solve the issue as I could manually do the form and insert it like <%= form_authenticity_token %>